# Java: TreeMap is there a nice way to search for duplicate strings as part of a composite key

Tags: java, java-8, treemap

I have a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) where the key is a composite key based on two fields. I would like to be able to search the `TreeMap` for matches on just the 2nd key element - there maybe duplicates of this element. To explain what I am trying to do please see the following,

```
public class CountySchoolsController {

    static TreeMap<StudentKey, Student> schoolsMap = new TreeMap<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        createSchoolsTreeMap();
        System.out.println(schoolsMap.get(new StudentKey(1, "Holmes")));
    }

    private static TreeMap<StudentKey, Student> createSchoolsTreeMap() {
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "Sherlock", "Holmes");
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "John", "Watson");
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Franklin", "Holmes");
        schoolsMap.put(new StudentKey(s1.getSchoolId(), s1.getLastname()), s1);
        schoolsMap.put(new StudentKey(s2.getSchoolId(), s2.getLastname()), s2);
        schoolsMap.put(new StudentKey(s3.getSchoolId(), s3.getLastname()), s3);
        return schoolsMap;
    }
}

public class StudentKey implements Comparable<StudentKey>{

    int schoolId;
    String lastname;

    public StudentKey(int id, String lastname){
        this.schoolId = id;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public int getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        StudentKey that = (StudentKey) o;
        return schoolId == that.schoolId &&
                Objects.equals(lastname, that.lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(schoolId, lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentKey o) {
        return (this.schoolId + this.lastname).compareTo(o.schoolId + o.lastname);
    }
}

public class Student {

    int schoolId;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;

    public Student(int schoolId, String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public int getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "schoolId=" + schoolId +
                ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

When I run this code it runs fine and prints the found `Student`,

> `Student{schoolId=1, firstname='Sherlock', lastname='Holmes'}`

What I would like to be able to do however is search just the `lastname` for `Holmes` and return two records represented by Ids 1 and 3. As well as doing searches likes this I also need the ability to do searches on an exact match on the key (as in the example above).

Ideally it would be nice if I could use a `wildcard` for `schoolId` but I don't think this is possible.

I could return the keyset values and iterate over this to find the match on just the `lastname` but I dont think this would be very **performant** - please tell me if you disagree or if this would be the best way to implement this ? Or should I be implementing this another way ?

Comment: I amended my answer.  I included a map of maps and some enums.  I also modified you classes somewhat to support the demo.  For each request, it checks to see if a map was made.  If it was, it used it for that attribute and sub attribute. (e.g. Lastname and Holmes, gender and female).  The next time thru the lists are all there for already created.  Let me know if have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  It streams the `entrySet` of the map, filtering only on the last name, then maps to the values associated with that name and puts it in a list.  I had to make the `lastname` field `public` for this.  Putting in `getters` for the fields would be useful.

```
        List<Student> list = schoolsMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().lastname
                        .equals("Holmes"))
                .map(Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I decided to go a little further on this.  If you put `getters` for all your  `key` attributes in your `StudentKey` class, you can do the following:

Get all the last names for `Holmes`

```
      List<Student> names = getStudentsForKeyAttribute(
                StudentKey::getLastName, "Holmes");

      names.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Get the student for `id = 3`

```
      List<Student> ids = getStudentsForKeyAttribute(StudentKey::getSchoolId, 3);

      ids.forEach(System.out.println);
```

The following method accepts an `AttributeExtractor` function to pull the appropriate attribute from the `StudentKey` and then filter based on the supplied argument.

```
        public <T> List<Student> getStudentsForKeyAttribute(
            Function<StudentKey, T> attrExtractor, T keyAttribute) {
            return schoolsMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> attrExtractor.apply(e.getKey())
                        .equals(keyAttribute))
                .map(Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

MAJOR EDIT:  I added data retention capabilities.  First time thru for each attribute it builds the map for that attribute and returns requested value. Future calls use existing map.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.function.Function;


// Main attribute for lookup
enum Attribute {
    LASTNAME, GENDER
}

// subattribute for gender.  For lastname it would jut be a name.
// I decided to use an enum for gender.
enum Gender {
    M, F, O
};

public class CompositeSearch {
    // Map of map.
    // Example:
    //   Outer Map is for LastName attribute
    //   Inner map as all lists for common last names.  All names are included.
    //     I had to use an Object to allow for different types (enums, strings, ints)
    Map<Attribute, Map<Object, List<Student>>> studentsByAttribute = new HashMap<>();


    // this provides an extractor for each type requested. It just maps the 
    // Attribute to the Student Key method call for that type.
    Map<Attribute, Function<StudentKey, ?>> extractorsForType = new HashMap<>() {
        {
            put(Attribute.LASTNAME,
                    StudentKey::getLastName);
            put(Attribute.GENDER, StudentKey::getGender);
        }
    };

    // intiial data base
    TreeMap<StudentKey, Student> schoolsMap = new TreeMap<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new CompositeSearch().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        createSchoolsTreeMap();

        // getting all female students.
        List<Student> list = getStudentsForKeyAttribute(
                Attribute.GENDER, Gender.F);

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        // getting all students with last name of holmes.
        list = getStudentsForKeyAttribute(Attribute.LASTNAME, "Holmes");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);

        // All maps for Gender and lastnames have been created so 
        // the lookups below require two map retrievals.  The attribute and the 
        // sub attribute
        System.out.println();
        list = getStudentsForKeyAttribute(
                Attribute.GENDER, Gender.M);

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        list = getStudentsForKeyAttribute(Attribute.LASTNAME, "Watson");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);


    }

    public <T> List<Student> getStudentsForKeyAttribute(
            Attribute attr, T keyAttribute) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Function<StudentKey, T> extractor = (Function<StudentKey, T>) extractorsForType
                .get(attr);

        if (!studentsByAttribute.containsKey(attr)) {
            // need to create the map.
            System.out.println("Building map for all " + attr);
            // sub attribute map
            Map<Object, List<Student>> subMap = new HashMap<>();

            studentsByAttribute.put(attr, subMap);

            for (Map.Entry<StudentKey, ?> e : schoolsMap
                    .entrySet()) {
              T subAttribute = extractor.apply(e.getKey());

                            subMap.compute(subAttribute,
                                    (k, v) -> v == null
                                            ?  new ArrayList<>()
                                            : v)
                            .add((Student)e.getValue());

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Using existing map for all " + attr);
        }
        return studentsByAttribute.get(attr).get(keyAttribute);

    }

    // from here on out, everything is pretty normal.
    private TreeMap<StudentKey, Student> createSchoolsTreeMap() {
        List<Student> students = List.of(
                new Student(1, "Sherlock", "Holmes",
                        Gender.M),
                new Student(2, "John", "Watson", Gender.M),
                new Student(3, "Franklin", "Holmes",
                        Gender.M),
                new Student(4, "Frances", "Holmes",
                        Gender.F),
                new Student(5, "Mary", "Wilson", Gender.F),
                new Student(6, "Martha", "Watson",
                        Gender.F));
        for (Student s : students) {
            schoolsMap.put(new StudentKey(s), s);
        }

        return schoolsMap;
    }

}

class StudentKey implements Comparable<StudentKey> {

    private int schoolId;
    private String lastname;
    private Gender gender;

    public StudentKey(Student student) {
        this.schoolId = student.getSchoolId();
        this.lastname = student.getLastname();
        this.gender = student.getGender();
    }

    public int getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        StudentKey that = (StudentKey) o;
        return schoolId == that.schoolId
                && Objects.equals(lastname, that.lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(schoolId, lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentKey o) {
        return (this.schoolId + this.lastname)
                .compareTo(o.schoolId + o.lastname);
    }

}

class Student {

    int schoolId;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    Gender gender;

    public Student(int schoolId, String firstname,
            String lastname, Gender gender) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public int getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "schoolId=" + schoolId
                + ", firstname='" + firstname + '\''
                + ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you thats a nice solution and runs well. My only thought is whether using a composite key and streams is the most performant solution. Would the streams process not have to pass through the whole structure to perform the matching?

Comment: I was wondering whether an alternative approach such as to create a second container which stores the lastname as a key and an arraylist of keys (id+lastname) as values. The search would then look up the key by lastname and then read through the arraylist to obtain the keys to the actual records. The keys would then be used to do the look-up on the schoolsmap - not sure if that approach would be more efficient - I guess I will simply have to benchmark both. Thanks again though - if your solution is as fast I will definitely use it.

Comment: You could have an enum representing the type of information you want.  LASTNAME, ID, CITY, etc.  Then you could have a map of maps.  Where the enum is the key.  If the map doesn't exist, you build it and simultaneously extract the current value you want to return.  The next time thru you can see LASTNAME maps exists and use it directly.  Unless the maps are serialized or stored in a data base you would need to create it each time you ran the app.  Also, if they are stored somehow, they would need to be updated for new students.

Comment: I've just implemented a second container and compared it with the streams solution and the difference in performance is quite surprising. Using the second container reduced the search and find time from 95ms to 1ms for a container holding 1,000,000 dummy created Student records with two randonly placed "Holmes" records. I guess it shouldn't be so surprising as this way greatly reduces the number of reads required.

Comment: I believe your way would be faster.  But I was trying to come up with a general attribute solution and not just focus on last names.

Comment: WJS - thank you thats a good idea. More flexible than the idea I've come up with. I also very much like your streams implementation I would prefer to use it as its more flexible and less code - but in this case performance is an issue. But I will mark yours as the answer though as it I would use it.

Comment: You said it reduced the number of reads required.  You should in effect need only one read.  I would presume for example, that you created a map of last names and the value was a 'List` of students with that last name.  So you use the map and instantly get the list of students for that name.

Comment: I implemented the following,
static Map<String, List<StudentKey>> secondContainer = new HashMap<>();
and then for the read I do,
List<Student> results = new ArrayList();
        if (secondContainer.containsKey(search)){
            List<StudentKey> keys = secondContainer.get(search);
            for (StudentKey key : keys){
                results.add(schoolsMap.get(key));
            }
        }
        return results;

Answer (score -1):

Well, filtering is cool, but slow. So if you want some performance - let's add index:

```
Map<String,Set<StudentKey>> lastNamesMap = new HashMap<>();

Set<StudentKey> getByLastName(String lastName) 
  return lastNamesMap.containsKey(s1.getLastname()) ? lastNamesMap.get(s1.getLastname()) : Collections.emptySet();  
}

void addStudent(Student s1) {
 final String k = s1.getLastname();
 Set<StudentKey> keys;
 if (lastNamesMap.containsKey(k)) {
  keys = lastNamesMap.get(k);
 } else {
  keys = new TreeSet<>();
 }
 StudentKey key = new StudentKey(s1.getSchoolId(), s1.getLastname();
 keys.add(key);
 lastNamesMap.put(k,keys);
 schoolsMap.put(key, s1);
 }
```